# Rails model inheritance with unique sets of fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-inheritance

I have a model BillService with basic set of fields. Next I want to create two models BillItem and BillGroup, which are the heirs of this and have the additional fields (each has a unique set). I also want to be able to get through the base class all instances of heirs and to check the class of concrete instance.

I can't imagine how to implement this. I tried to google it but nothing succeeded. I read about STI. That's what I need?

Comment: Yes, `STI` is better way to go here.

Comment: @ArupRakshit,
Following STI, I should create table with union of all fieldsets?

Comment: Yes all fields. :) With STI, we have one table, with a added `type` _string_ inside the field.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord has native support of STI architecture.

1. Create BillService model

`class BillService < ActiveRecord::Base`

`end`

2. Create an folder bill_service and create your sti model in this folder

`class BillService < ActiveRecord::Base`

`end`

3. Add type field in your table bill_services

`add_column :bill_services, :type, :string`

4. Migrate

`rake db:migrate`

5. Use your STI

`rails c`

`BillService::BillItem.all`

`BillService::BillItem.new`

it's equal at

`BillService.where(type: 'BillService::BillItem')`

ActiveRecord set automatically type field by YouModel::YourSubModel.